# Pass a string as method parameter to be interpolated later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to pass a string to a method in ruby and have that method interpolate that string?

I have something like this in mind:

```
do_a_search("location = #{location}")
...
def do_a_search(search_string)
  location = .... #get this from another source
  Model.where(search_string)
end
```

The context is RoR but this is a general ruby question I think. I realise the example above looks a bit convoluted but I'm trying to refactor a bunch of very repetitive methods.

The issue is that if I put the string to be interpolated in double quotes, location doesn't exist when the method is called, if I put it in single quotes, it will never be interpolated...

What I really want to do is put it in single quotes and interpolate it later. I don't think this is possible, or am I missing something?

**edit:** to be clear (as I think I have oversimplified what I'm trying to do above), one of the issues here is that I might want to call this method in multiple contexts; I might actually want to call

```
do_a_search("country = #{country}")
```

or even

```
do_a_search("country = #{country} AND location = #{location})
```

(country also existing as a local var within my method). I therefore want to pass everything necessary for the substitution in my method call

I think the String.interpolate method from the facets gem would solve my problem but it doesn't work in rails 4

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the *location doesn't exist when the method is called* part. Do you mean, inside the method itself, the variable you wrote `location = .... #get this from another source` doesn't contain the string you passed in?

Comment: I don't think my variable names helped here - what I mean that the "location" local var doesn't exist until it's created in the first line of the method - it doesn't exist at the time of the method call

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For that purpose, `%` is used. First, create a string:

```
s = "location = %{location}"
```

Later, you can apply `%` to it:

```
s % {location: "foo"} # => "location = foo"
```

If you do not have to name the parameter(s), then it is simpler:

```
s = "location = %s"
s % "foo" # => "location = foo"
```

Comment: Good answer, but the issue is that it requires my method to know something about the string to be substituted - see my edit

Comment: @sparky Use the last example Sawa showed; I think that's what you want (unless I'm still unclear). In that case it comes down to the order in which the placeholders appear, much like an SQL parameterized query. The caller  (whoever created the string to be passed in), must ensure the string is written correctly so the method does not blow up.

Comment: @sparky: This doesn't require your method to know anything that the `"#{str}"` syntax doesn't. You just use entries in a Hash instead of local variables.

Comment: Quite right, sorry. This would work but I think I would get into issues over number of parameters etc.  However, it answers the question I originally posed so I have accepted it. The String.interpolate method I think was originally looking for doesn't actually exist, but can be created, see below

Comment: @sparky: I don't quite see how you imagine this would get into issues over number of parameters. `String#%` doesn't care about how many additional entries there are in the hash. You'd just use a hash or struct as the context for the interpolation rather than the implicit local context.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned above, the [Facets Gem](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/string/interpolate.rb) would help with this, but doesn't seem to work in rails 4

However its code to extend String is very simple:

```
class String
  def self.interpolate(&str)
    eval "%{#{str.call}}", str.binding
  end
end
```

I think that implementing & then using that inside the method is the most sensible way of doing what I'm looking for, but I'll accept Sawa's answer, because as Paul Richter & Chuck point out, it would I think work, but at the risk of "blowing up" if I don't quite get the calls right.

Comment: What did you end up doing ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is basically a format string, so I think you'd be better served by sprintf or `%`.

```
do_a_search("location = %s")
...
def do_a_search(search_string)
  location = .... #get this from another source
  Model.where(search_string % location)
end
```

If you have multiple things you want to interpolate and don't want to enforce an order, you can use a Hash and named specifiers.

```
do_a_search("location = %{location}")
...
def do_a_search(search_string)
  location = .... #get this from another source
  Model.where(search_string % {location: location})
end
```

Comment: Surely it would need to be `search_string % {name: location}` then? Since you declared it as `%{name}` in the String, rather than `%{location}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can late-bind the extrapolation by using [`binding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Binding.html) and `ERB`:

```
require 'erb'

def do_a_search(search_string)
  location = 'this'
  ERB.new(search_string).result(binding)
end

do_a_search('location = <%= location %>')
# => "location = this"
```

Or, you can directly use `eval`:

```
def do_a_search(search_string)
  location = 'this'
  eval search_string, binding
end

do_a_search('"location = #{location}"')
# => "location = this"
```

This will, of course, be acceptable only if the strings you receive in `do_a_search` are trusted and/or sanitized.