# How can I ruby to use its input define the format of output for a method

Tags: ruby, methods, eval

I have the following method:

```
def response_array_to_list(response_array, line_item)

    output_line = ''

    response_array.each_with_index do | item, index |
      output_line = output_line + line_item + "\n"
    end

    return output_line
end
```

`line_item` is intended to define the format and contents of `output_line`.

For example, I would like to pass as line_item something like: `#{index} - #{item['value']['keyword']) at #{item['value']['time_string']`

I obviously can't since `item` and `index` are in scope only inside of the method.  But that's the idea.

It usage should look *something* like this:

```
response_array_to_list(response_array, `#{index} - #{item['value']['keyword']) at #{item['value']['time_string']`

=> 1 - keyword here at 10AM
   2 - keyword there at 12PM
```

**QUESTION:**  How can I pass something that does NOT try to substitute the variables when an input to the method, but does interpret it as intended within the method.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks. You are already using them (as method caller, like `each_with_index do ... end`), now it's time to use them from the other side (as method creator). Blocks are pieces of code that are not evaluated immediately, right?

Your "usage" should be like this:

```
response_array_to_list(response_array) { |item, index|
  "#{index} - #{item['value']['keyword']} at #{item['value']['time_string']}"
}
```

and your method:

```
def response_array_to_list(response_array)

    output_line = ''

    response_array.each_with_index do | item, index |
      line_item = yield item, index
      output_line = output_line + line_item + "\n"
    end

    return output_line
end
```

or, equivalently, this optimised version:

```
def response_array_to_list(response_array)    
    response_array.each_with_index.map { |item, index|
      yield item, index
    }.join("\n") + "\n"
end
```

**EDIT** If you need dynamic templates (i.e. not hardcoded), you can use e.g. Liquid as mentioned in comments for safe processing:

```
require 'liquid'
def response_array_to_list(response_array, template)
  compiledTemplate = Liquid::Template.parse(template)
  response_array.each_with_index.map { |item, index|
    compiledTemplate.render 'index' => index, 'item' => item
  }
end

response_array_to_list(response_array, "{{index}} - {{item['value']['keyword']}} at {{item['value']['time_string']}}")
```

Comment: My methods needs as an input the string which contains the variable to be interpolated.  That is not hard coded as you have. That is the challenge.

Comment: Oh wait maybe I am not following. What does yield do?

Comment: That is dangerous territory. You could use `eval`, but you should never ever evaluate a string you are not 100% sure is safe. Where do your template strings come from? Do they have a restricted selection of variables? Templates might work, especially safe ones like Liquid. `yield` gives the values to the block.

Comment: In theory there are never user inputs for what needs to get interpolated inside the method. I was reading about the facets gem which provides an interpolate string method but still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had found someone else's post in SO here:

[Passing a method a string to be interpolated later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371451/passing-a-method-a-string-to-be-interpolated-later)

The solution was to use the `facets` gem and require the `string/interpolate` method.

`line_item_interpolated = String.interpolate {line_item}`